# Pull Windows Shortcut into JButton of a JFrame like in Turbolaunch

Tags: java, windows, swing, icons, jbutton

is it possible to pull a windows shortcut(e.g. for a Programm like Word) into a JButton of a JFrame.
This JButton should now have the icon of the Shorcut which i pulled to it and the path to start the Programm.

*(i dont know if someone know the Programm "Turbolaunch"...it should do something like it)*

i already did some work...but at the moment i have to code all the Shortcuts and Icons manually

i hope you can help me.

[image: picture of my example Programm]